# HTTP GET Request, Response

Tags: get-request, getresponse

I have a file where I send GET request to another file, and I got the response show up under Network tab of Google Dev Tools, but it did not display on my browser.

This is what I do for passing the response to display in my browser.

```js
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4){
                
                res = xmlhttp.responseText;
                
                document.getElementById('table3').innerHTML = res;
            }
        }
```

And I want to display the response under the table of id = "table3" like below.

```html
<td id="table3"> 
<td>
```

The content inside was passing from the response of GET request.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that your if statement in the `onreadystatechange` callback is wrong. xmlhttp is the instance of the XHR class, which would mean that instead of using `this`, you would have to use `xmlhttp`, and not `this`. `this` in the context of your program likely is the `window` object.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now after staring at it for hours. :D

Comment: Haha, that’s alright! It happens to the best of us.